# looking for an analytic solution of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+ay+b\sqrt y+cx=\text{const.}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After one integration of some problem the next second-order ODE is appeared:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+ay+b\sqrt y+cx=\text{const.}$$

Is it possible to solve it analytically?